# PHP MongoDB updateMany - use $in in $filter array

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

Let there be given a number of documents with unique property "id", and a property "updated".

```
{"id": 1, "updated": false}, 
{"id": 2, "updated": false}, 
...
{"id": 100, "updated": false}
```

Let's suppose I, through PHP, want to update documents with id-s

```
$php_ids = [11, 14, 23, 35]
```

and set "updated" to 'true'.

Generally, MongoDB updateMany($filter, $update, array $options = []) method is used. Documentation at https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.2/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-updateMany/ gives following example:

```
$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->test->restaurants;

$updateResult = $collection->updateMany(
[ 'borough' => 'Queens' ],
[ '$set' => [ 'active' => 'True' ]]
);
```

Yet I couldn't find an example of how to use $in in filter (first argument to updateMany method), to include my $php_ids in query.

Answer (score 0):

Partly thanks to this example
https://hotexamples.com/examples/mongodb/Collection/updateMany/php-collection-updatemany-method-examples.html

I've come up with solution to my problem:

```
 $filter = [
        'id' => ['$in' => $php_ids]
    ];
 $update = ['$set' => ['processed' => true]];

 $mongo_collection->updateMany($filter, $update);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do same thing with update method also.
like below.(nosqlBooster syntax)

```
db.yourCollectionName.update(
    { "id": { '$in': [11, 14, 23, 35] } },
    { $set: { "updated": "true" } },
    { multi: true });
```

Comment: Thanks @amit-joshi! Is this PHP way btw?